# Web Push Notification - How to store Vapid Key

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, web-push

Hi I generate the VAPID key using the following function, as I had searched, vapid key shall be created only once for a project and we can use that a vapid key while sending push notifications, I had generated the vapid key, but I have to store the vapid key in some place and retrieve them whenever sending a push notification. Please advice how can I store the vapid key

```
fun generateVapidPublicKey(uniqueVisitorId: String): String {

    val keyPair= this.webPushService.generateVapidKeyPair()
    val publicKey = keyPair!!.public as ECPublicKey

    val encodedPublicKey = Utils.encode(publicKey)

    return Base64Encoder.encodeUrl(encodedPublicKey)
}
```

Convert to KeyPair from string

```
fun generateKeyPair(): KeyPair {

    return KeyPair(
            Utils.loadPublicKey("ODyt-8tafKI35yE-tz9eLah0goe63CeFYGmnmIaLe8="),
            Utils.loadPrivateKey(
                    "BPO9QDvvjnLCAusoZ1vXZQjVaCG3sOP9vd-VHSUOoN3Jj3VXXSQPzQ31NMrK76N-eODmioJXUpN0gfoIBORZrt="
            )
    )
}
```

**Throws "Invalid point encoding 0x38"**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use only one vapid key per project. You can store the vapid key in your database or in a configuration file.

Comment: I had stored them in Mongodb database as string, but when sending push notification, I need to convert them to key pair again.. How to do this.. I had added the function I had used to covert them back to keyPair but it throws "Invalid point encoding 0x38" error .Please have a look at the updated question

Comment: The private key of the VAPID pair is to be kept secret. If you check-in this in plain text view in the code repository, you risk the secret being stolen. Any hacker with the VAPID pair will be able to subscribe and send push messages to your users impersonating you.